# Change link on official FAQ page

Tags: feature-request

The last section in the Stack Overflow official FAQ, https://stackoverflow.com/faq#what-about, currently links to a search of the questions tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq). I think it would be more helpful if instead it linked to the [FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites). This is a much more organized list and would be more helpful to a new user.

EDIT: Since each meta-site has its own separate FAQ tag, it may be more useful to link each site to a search of its FAQ-tagged meta-questions, as well as have a link to the FAQ index. Since the index is entitled "FAQ for Stack Exchange sites", it's applicable to all sites. Mostly I would like to see this page linked on the official FAQ because:

- It is community edited (isn't that the whole idea of SE?)
- It is far easier to update (probably because of that last one)
- It is, literally, the most often asked questions on MSO.

Comment: Keep in mind that that section of the [faq] is the same all across the network.  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#what-about  Not all sites have an faq index.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff Yes, I see. I've edited my question to clarify my request.

Answer (score 2):

I'd argue that [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) is *far* more generally useful than The Massive Index. Yes, if you want to sit down and read *all about Stack Exchange* the Index is a good start - but if you're just looking for an answer to *a specific question*, searching the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) is much quicker.

I do it all the time when answering support questions. Whereas, I think the last time I opened The FAQ was to look for an obsolete entry that I thought was hiding there and needed to be removed (but someone beat me to it).

Comment: Plus, sorting the [faq] search by votes gives you the index post at the top anyway.